# Is it possible to execute a custom program at compile time?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to execute a custom program at compile time?

Example:

```
trait Component..
struct Position..
impl Component for Position..
struct Direction..
impl Component for Direction..
```

Now I want to count the number of `impl` of `Component` at compile time. In this case it would be 2. Then I could access this variable in my program like `number_of_components`.

Would something like this be doable with Rust or Rustc and where would I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust doesn't have CTFE, so I don't think so.

I think that the only way to do this would be to create the impls/structs via a macro, maybe? But any ones that weren't generated from the macro would not be in that count.